# how to read a csv file from wasb using sparkr language

Tags: azure-blob-storage, jupyter-notebook, sparkr

I want to read a csv file from the wasb in storage account using sparkr language.I'm using the jupyter notebook for implementing it.It will be great if anyone can help me with examples.

Answer (score 1):

The file can be read using the following command,

iris_data <- read.df(path = "", source = "com.databricks.spark.csv")

It is working perfect.Thanks everyone

Comment: Thanks for providing your solution. Please mark your reply as answer. A thread which has answer can be more easier searched. It will help others who encountered similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage doesn't provide R language client library. To get a blob using R, you could call the REST API provided by Azure Storage. The HTTP request message could be like this.

```
GET https://{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{containername}/{blobname} HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2016-05-31
x-ms-date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 02:21:00 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey {accountname}:{yoursharedkey}
Host: {storagename}.blob.core.windows.net
```

The content of this blob will be returned in the response body. You could search on web to find how to send REST request using sparkr language.

[Bing Search: Call REST API from R](https://www.bing.com/search?q=call%20rest%20api%20from%20R)